# How to change position of attributes in compare products

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, compare

Magento 2.1 in the "More Information" of products page position. It's okay but when I compare position it incorrect 
such as the product page  attribute positions `1 2 3 4` but in compare `2 3 4 1`.

1 is my new attribute and 2 3 4 are my old attributes.

Answer (score 1):

On product, page attributes are sorted like in attribute set. But on the comparison product page attributes are not sorted at all.
You have to override function **getComparableAttributes** in

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Compare/Item/Collection.php

Here is Overridden function:

```
 public function getComparableAttributes()
        {
            if ($this->_comparableAttributes === null) {
                $this->_comparableAttributes = [];
                $setIds = $this->_getAttributeSetIds();
                if ($setIds) {
                    $attributeIds = $this->_getAttributeIdsBySetIds($setIds);
        
                    $select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
                        ['main_table' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute')]
                    )->join(
                        ['additional_table' => $this->getTable('catalog_eav_attribute')],
                        'additional_table.attribute_id=main_table.attribute_id'
                    )->joinLeft(
                        ['al' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute_label')],
                        'al.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id AND al.store_id = ' . (int)$this->getStoreId(),
                        [
                            'store_label' => $this->getConnection()->getCheckSql(
                                'al.value IS NULL',
                                'main_table.frontend_label',
                                'al.value'
                            )
                        ]
                    )
                            ->joinLeft( //add sort order to sort the attributes as per backend sort.
                        ['as' => $this->getTable('eav_entity_attribute')],
                        'as.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id'
                    )
                            ->where(
                        'additional_table.is_comparable=?',
                        1
                    )->where(
                        'main_table.attribute_id IN(?)',
                        $attributeIds
                    )
                     ->where("as.attribute_set_id in (?)", $setIds)
                            ->order('as.sort_order') //sort by sort_order
                            ;
                    $attributesData = $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
                    if ($attributesData) {
                        $entityType = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY;
                        $this->_eavConfig->importAttributesData($entityType, $attributesData);
                        foreach ($attributesData as $data) {
                            $attribute = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute($entityType, $data['attribute_code']);
                            $this->_comparableAttributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute;
                        }
                        unset($attributesData);
                    }
                }
            }
            return $this->_comparableAttributes;
        }
```

Working fine in Magento 2.4.0